# Cryptonight mining on Raspberry Pi

Tags: cryptonight, mining-hardware, mining-pool-setup, raspberry-pi, bytecoin

Recently I found out about cryptonight algorithms, Bytecoin in specific. I have about 20 Raspberry Pi’s here and I would like to know if cryptonight mining is possible on ARM processors.

I am also planning to join a pool, so the mining software needs to be compatible with pools.

Thanks!

Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get about ~10H/s in my experience.

I use https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi

(You may need to switch to the ARM fork on the repo).
You should be able to compile it once then `scp` it to your devices.

Here's another thread that may be helpful:
[Could I use a Raspberry Pi to mine Monero?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/could-i-use-a-raspberry-pi-to-mine-monero/6888#6888)

Also with this number of devices, you may want to add proxy:
https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig-proxy

Simplifies your management greatly.

Comment: Isn’t a proxy used to bridge the use of a getwork network (from the miner) to a stratum server (to the pool), why do I need a proxy in this scenario?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking so I'll just give a little more .. In this usage, it aggregates the connections so that between the pool and the proxy there is a single connection. You'd point your 20 devices at the proxy. Then in the event you wanted to change pools, you'd change the proxy instead of each of your 20 RPis.  (On a side note if that is you SOLO mining on GCM - wishing you great luck!!) Most pool operators would object to 20 threads open for such small miners. GCM is so new  I don't mind at all. Feel free to configure each miner or a proxy.